# numpy.array() is not converting tiff image to 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, tiff

I have been trying to figure out why the numpy.array() method is converting my tiff image into an object (dtype=object). I tried this with other tiff images and I did not encounter this problem. I am pretty sure it has to do something with how my "actin2.tif" image is acquired. I just need to be able to convert this particular tiff image to a 2D array. This is what my code looks like:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> a = Image.open('actin2.tif')
>>> a_array = numpy.array(a)
>>> a
<PIL.TiffImagePlugin.TiffImageFile image mode=I;16B size=37x58 at 0x14BBC68>
>>> a_array
array(<PIL.TiffImagePlugin.TiffImageFile image mode=I;16B size=37x58 at 0x14BBC68>, dtype=object)
```

I eventually need to be able to manipulate the value of the pixels in the image and I cannot do that without the image being converted to a 2D array. Currently, this is the error thrown when I try to manipulate the array:

```
structure_masked = numpy.multiply(structure_mask,image)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'bool' and 'instance'
```

which is a result from this line of code:

```
structure_masked = numpy.multiply(structure_mask,image)
```

"structure_mask" and "image" were converted to numpy arrays in the same way as mentioned above.

I have tried changing mode and dtype but that does not seem to be working, any suggestions?

Comment: What does the array represent? RGB requires three arrays. Hue/sat requires two I think.

Comment: @xaav in numpy, this would just be a single 4-dimensional array.

Comment: What's the fourth dimension?

Comment: @xaav sorry, 3 dimensions, but the point is, it would be a single multidimensional array.

Comment: Anyway, it seems to me that this may be an issue with your version of PIL. what version are you on?

Comment: `import imageio; im = imageio.imread('actin2.tif')`

Comment: Also `pip install imageio`.

Comment: Do you notice a difference with `Image.load()` instead of `Image.open()`? `Image.open()` is a lazy/deferred operation whereas `Image.load()` is an explicit call to load pixel data. If that doesn't work, try `numpy.array(a.getdata())`. Also does `show()` work?

Comment: Can you post the exact image? It works with arbitrary image on me.

Answer (score 0):

Ran across this same problem.  Turned out we were running PIL instead of Pillow.  This fixed it for us:

> sudo pip uninstall PIL
>
> sudo pip install pillow -U

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a = Image.open('actin2.tif')
>>> a_array = numpy.array(a)
>>> a # you are printing the image not array.
```

you are printing image instead of array. It should be `>>>a_array` 
instead of `>>>a`